# Why does 全員 sound like zein but is written zenin (ぜんいん)?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Is the middle "n" silent? Am I just not used to hearing it and can't identify it?

- The duolingo pronunciation sounds like "zein" https://www.duolingo.com/dictionary/Japanese/%E5%85%A8%E5%93%A1/46748a7b24925ca8284f992c47fdfa40
- The two femails pronounce it as "zenin" while the male and AI pronounce it "zein" - https://forvo.com/word/%E5%85%A8%E5%93%A1/
- The hiragana spelling I got is from https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%A8%E5%93%A1

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4704/y-sound-insertion-after-intervocalic-%e3%82%93, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11980/pronunciation-of-%e3%83%af%e3%83%b3%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3%e9%81%8b%e8%bb%a2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That intermediate ん is still there.  Really.  When pronounced between two vowels, ん often causes nasality, without the speaker fully closing the airway -- so it doesn't sound like an English //n// or //ŋ//.  Also, if you listen carefully and pay attention to the length of time it takes to say, ぜんいん is truly four [morae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_(Japanese_prosody)) (four beats), while ぜいん is only three.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure there are related questions on the site.  I'm just not having a good search-fu kind of day.

Comment: Before the vowels i or e, it can also take on a bit of a "y" sound (while still also having a definite nasalization: still sounding like "n" but without touching the tongue to the roof), which happens with 全員 and also a word like 万円 (which I've always imagined probably led to the English translation of the 円 to be "yen").

Comment: The effect is a lot like "final n" in French; or ã in Portuguese. Though I have heard some French speakers overdoing it when they speak Japanese - starting the nasalization early in the preceding vowel (as you would in French), rather than about at the mora where an n "would be".